# Change the value of specific tag in xml file using maven

Tags: maven, plugins, compilation, wso2, pom.xml

I have the following tag into my xml file

```
<sequence name="Producers_Codes_In" onError="Producers_Fault" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
```

I want to replace the attribute name="Producers_Codes_In" to name="Producers_Codes_In-1.0.0". this I have to do with maven.
Actually can rename the attributes in the artifacts of project using maven-antrun-plugin in this way

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>artifacts_version</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <replaceregexp byline="true">
              <regexp pattern="version=&quot;(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)(-SNAPSHOT)?&quot;" />
              <substitution expression=" version=&quot;${project.version}&quot;" />
              <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="artifact.xml" />
              </fileset>
            </replaceregexp>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

the problem comes when I specify the file that a want to change.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer. The key to cover all file is the attribute --> flag="g" like in this example

```
<replaceregexp 
    match=" context=&quot;/producers/(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)&quot;"
    replace=" context=&quot;/producers/${project.version}&quot;" 
    flags="g" 
    byline="true">
       <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.xml" />
    </replaceregexp>
```

go to this page for more information https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html